# ¿ Como devolver la URL anterior en C# siendo esta de un dominio diferente al actual?

Tags: javascript, c#, html5, visual-studio

Tengo una web desarrollada con asp .Net (Webforms) que necesita hacer un pago. Antes de realizar el pago estoy aun en el dominio de la web. En el momento de realizar el pago se redirige al usuario a otro dominio de la plataforma de pago y una vez hecho  el cobro la misma plataforma de pago llama a una pagina de la web para notificar que el pago es correcto.

El problema que surje es que nadie puede entrar a esa pagina de confirmacion de pago de la web excepto la plataforma de pago. Por eso necesito alguna forma de saber cual fue la pagina anterior a la que llamo a esta pagina de la web que confirma el pago.

He probado con:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer
```

Pero el resultado siempre es 'null' y puede ser porque la pagina anterior que llamo a la actual no es del mismo dominio.
Necesito alguna manera de saber que esa pagina ha sido llamada desde una url en concreto aunque tenga diferente dominio.

Es decir:

Tenemos una pagina inicial con nombre "pagina1.aspx" que redirecciona a la plataforma de pago  "https://sitio-de-pago.com/realizarpago". Una vez realizado el pago en esta plataforma redirecciona a la pagina "ConfirmacionPago.aspx". En la pagina "ConfirmacionPago.aspx" queremos saber si ha sido llamada desde la url "https://sitio-de-pago.com/realizarpago"

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se realiza una redirección a un dominio diferente, el valor de la propiedad UrlReferrer se establece en null por razones de seguridad. Sin embargo, existen otras opciones que puedes considerar para obtener la información que necesitas.

Una posible solución es agregar un parámetro a la URL que redirige al usuario al sitio de pago, que indique la URL de la página anterior. Por ejemplo, si la página que realiza la redirección se llama ***Pagina1.aspx*** y la página de confirmación de pago se llama ***ConfirmacionPago.aspx***, la URL de redirección podría ser algo así:

```
https://sitio-de-pago.com/pagar.aspx?paginaAnterior=Pagina1.aspx
```

En la página de confirmación de pago, puedes obtener el valor del parámetro `paginaAnterior` utilizando el objeto Request de ASP.NET:

```
string paginaAnterior = Request.QueryString["paginaAnterior"];
```

Otra opción es almacenar la URL de la página anterior en una cookie antes de realizar la redirección al sitio de pago. Luego, en la página de confirmación de pago, puedes leer el valor de la cookie:

```
string paginaAnterior = Request.Cookies["paginaAnterior"].Value;
```

Ten en cuenta que la utilización de cookies puede presentar ciertos problemas de seguridad si no se implementan correctamente. Asegúrate de tomar las medidas necesarias para proteger la información almacenada en las cookies.

Espero que esto te sea de ayuda. ¡Buena suerte!

Comment: necesito saber la URL de la pagina de pago que llama a la pagina de ConfirmacionPago.aspx y que efectivamente se haya redireccionado a ConfirmacionPago.aspx desde esa URL de sitio de pago ejemplo: "https://sitio-pago.com/realizarPago